# Unable to connect to www.googleapis.com from GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-api, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have an application running in my GKE cluster that needs access to `www.googleapis.com`. I also make use of Network Policy to enhance security.

With a default deny all egress traffic in place, I cannot connect to `www.googleapis.com` naturally. I get the error

```
INFO 0827 14:33:53.313241 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #3...
DEBUG 0827 14:33:53.313862 http_wrapper.py] Caught socket error, retrying: timed out
DEBUG 0827 14:33:53.314035 http_wrapper.py] Retrying request to url https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=development&projection=noAcl&key=AIzaSyDnac<key>bmJM&fields=nextPageToken%2Citems%2Fid&alt=json&maxResults=1000 after exception timed out
```

I found out that the hostname `www.googleapis.com` corresponds to the IP `216.58.207.36`

So I went ahead an created an egress entry in my Network Policy

```
  spec:
    egress:
    - ports:
      - port: 443
        protocol: TCP
      to:
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: 216.58.207.36/32
```

And now from within the Pod, I can telnet this endpoint

```
$ telnet googleapis.com 443
Trying 216.58.207.36...
Connected to googleapis.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

But for some reason Im still encountering the same error

```
INFO 0827 14:36:15.767508 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #5...
DEBUG 0827 14:36:15.768018 http_wrapper.py] Caught socket error, retrying: timed out
DEBUG 0827 14:36:15.768128 http_wrapper.py] Retrying request to url https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=development&projection=noAcl&key=AIzaSyDnac<key>bmJM&fields=nextPageToken%2Citems%2Fid&alt=json&maxResults=1000 after exception timed out
```

However if I delete the network policy, I can connect

```
INFO 0827 14:40:24.177456 base_api.py] Body: (none)
INFO 0827 14:40:24.177595 transport.py] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
WARNING 0827 14:40:24.177864 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Credentials file could not be loaded, will ignore and overwrite.
DEBUG 0827 14:40:24.177957 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Read credential file
WARNING 0827 14:40:24.178036 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Credentials file could not be loaded, will ignore and overwrite.
DEBUG 0827 14:40:24.178090 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Read credential file
WARNING 0827 14:40:24.356631 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Credentials file could not be loaded, will ignore and overwrite.
DEBUG 0827 14:40:24.356972 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Read credential file
DEBUG 0827 14:40:24.357510 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Wrote credential file /var/lib/jenkins/.gsutil/credstore2.
connect: (www.googleapis.com, 443)
send: 'GET /storage/v1/b?project=development&fields=nextPageToken%2Citems%2Fid&alt=json&projection=noAcl&maxResults=1000 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.googleapis.com\r\ncontent-length: 0\r\nauthorization: REDACTED
```

My Network Policy allows ALL ingress traffic by default

```
ingress:
- {}
podSelector: {}
```

Any idea what I might be missing here ? Is there some other IP address that I need to whitelist in this case ?

**EDIT**

When the network Policy is in place, I did a test using `curl` and I get

```
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4001:80b::200a...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4001:80b::200a: Cannot assign requested address
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4001:80b::200a...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4001:80b::200a: Cannot assign requested address
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4001:80b::200a...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4001:80b::200a: Cannot assign requested address
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4001:80b::200a...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4001:80b::200a: Cannot assign requested address
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4001:80b::200a...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4001:80b::200a: Cannot assign requested address
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4001:80b::200a...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4001:80b::200a: Cannot assign requested address
```

This does not happen when the Network Policy is deleted.

Comment: www.googleapis.com does NOT correspond to the IP 172.217.13.109 - the IP changes based on location, time, etc. You cannot rely on it staying the same.

Comment: Please post the whole network policy `yaml`.

Comment: If you do `nslookup googleapis.com` from 5 different locations, you would end up with 30 IP addresses to whitelist, and even then, it wouldn't be necessarily valid tomorrow. You need a different approach, like Istio.

Answer (score 3):

The comment from @mensi is correct, there are multiple IPs behind www.googleapis.com. You can for example see that by pinging the URL multiple times, you'll most likely get a different IP every time.

The easiest solution would be to allow all egress by default with:

```
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

You could also try allowing all of the Google API's public IP ranges, but as Google doesn't seem to publish a list of those (only the restricted.googleapis.com and private.googleapis.com [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access-hybrid)), that might be a bit tougher.